# Enterd time is not found in text file show Not found message in php

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have login form when user login i am writing login name and login time on text file. I have text box like time when i enter time in that box and click submit I want search based on time showing username and time details fine.But when i entered time not found on textfile it showing nothing.I want to show the Nothing found message.I have tried so many ways but it didn't work.Please somebody help me. Thanks in Advance.

### this is my text filedata

### name  logintime            ip       system name

Abc  |29/12/17 12:35:54  |192.168.0.101|CentaurOne
John |29/12/17 12:37:41  |192.168.0.101|CentaurOne
cena |29/12/17 01:02:15  |192.168.0.101|CentaurOne
Abc  |29/12/17 01:20:25  |192.168.0.101|CentaurOne

### this is mycode

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))

{

$time = $_POST['time']; 

foreach ($new as $login => $data) {
    foreach ($data as $name => $dates) {
        if (!is_array($dates)) continue ;   

            foreach ($dates as $date) {
            if (strpos($date, $time) !== false) {
                echo $login."-";
                echo $matches[$login][] = $date ."<br>";

            }  

            else {
                   echo "No data found";
                 }      
        }

    }

        }


}
```

Comment: Add `else` clause after `if (strpos($date, $time) !== false) {}`

Comment: I tried it's not working

Comment: Ok, delete ` !== false` from the `if` and check again.

Comment: If I removed also not working

Comment: Does your code work if you provide an existing time ?

Comment: Yes I am getting list of details if matches

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Try like this

```
   if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
    $time = $_POST['time']; 
    $value=false;
    foreach ($new as $login => $data) {
        foreach ($data as $name => $dates) {
            if (!is_array($dates)) continue ;   

                foreach ($dates as $date) {
                if (strpos($date, $time) !== false) {
                    $value=true;
                    echo $login."-";
                    echo $matches[$login][] = $date ."<br>";

                }  


            }

        }

        }    
    }if(!$value){
     echo 'nothing found';
}
```